# jQuery Option De-Select Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to detect the event where an option is de-selected from a select element.  So for instance, if my HTML is:

```
<select id="select_box">
    <option value="1">Hot</option>
    <option value="2">Cold</option>
    <option value="3">Just Right</option>
</select>
```

And the second option is selected (`value="2"`), and then the user de-selects it by clicking on another option (such as `value="3"`) or clicking the same option again, how do I detect that event using jQuery?  My goal is to fire off a function when it happens.

I tried the following:

```
$("#select_box option:selected").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: The JQuery documentation specifiies that you should use it on the select element itself (http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `change` event should go on the `select` element itself:

```
$("#select_box").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

This event fires when the value of the select is changed and will match the behaviour you require.

---

> I want the value of the option that was de-selected.

In that case you would need to store the previous value when it's selected, something like this:

```
$("#select_box").change(function() {
    var $select = $(this),
        currentValue = $select.val(),
        oldValue = $select.data('previous-value');

    // do stuff...

    $select.data('previous-value', currentValue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rory.  The thing is, I want the value of the option that was de-selected.  I think what you wrote will give me the value of the newly selected option instead.

Comment: Thanks again! This is very helpful. The only thing I can't figure out is how to set `oldValue` when there is no `'previous-value'` in `$select.data()` (i.e. when the user clicks inside the select element for the first time).  Is there anything like Python's `dict.get(key, default=None)` method?

Comment: Not specifically, but you could set it on load: `$('select').each(function() { $(this).data('previous-value', $(this).val()) });`, or you could make each select default to an empty value to force a selection to be made.

Comment: Actually I gleaned the solution from @f00bar's answer below: `oldValue = $select.data('previous-value') || []` does the trick by returning an empty array if there's no `'previous-value'`.  Thank you for your help; your answer went 95% of the way toward solving my problem so it gets the green check.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how I would handle this with with a change Event listener.

```
$("#select_box").on('change', function(e){
    var $t = $(this), data = $t.data('last') || {optText:'none', val:'none'};
    $t.next().text('last was ['+data.optText+'] and its value is "'+data.val+'"').end()
      .data('last', {optText:$t.children('[value="'+$t.val()+'"]').text(), val:$t.val()});
});
```

Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/stphane/EvbcP/)

Answer (score 0):

I would enable the element when the option is selected using the `one()` event binding method

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However after reading the docs on the `one()` event binding method, it's not clear to me how to apply it to my situation.

Comment: Nevermind, Rory solution is much better than event bind messing.

Answer (score 0):

change event will fired only when value is changed which is required by you

```
        $("#select_box").change(function() {
            console.log(this.value);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually some thing like below code i given,

```
var xSelectedOption = 0;

$("#select_box").change(function() {

    if(xSelectedOption != $(this).val())
    {
      xSelectedOption = $(this).val();

      console.log("Option was changed!");
    }  

});
```